# C# textbox to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I'm sure this is really simple to do but i'm struggling.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveBtn();


        void SaveBtn()
        {

            string savetext = textBox1.Text;
            string savetext2 = textBox2.Text;


            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Riot Games\AccountSwitcher.txt", savetext + Environment.NewLine + savetext2 + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            MessageBox.Show("Your ID: " + savetext + " and you PWD: " + savetext2 + " has been saved.");


        }

    }
```

As you can see i have 2 textbox and when i'm clicking the button "save" both input are saved into a file.txt. This code works like a charm but i'd rather save these 2 inputs into an array so i could use them individually.

Thanks your help, i'm pretty noob as you can see so please keep it simple :D <3

Comment: An array of what? char? strings? what would be the separator of the array? You gotta be more specific and demonstrate at least one try when making questions

Comment: You can already use them individually..?

Comment: string[] saved = new string[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text };

Comment: Yes thank you guys ! I had this idea in mind but i didn't know how to write it ! It was so simple. How can i mark this question as "answered"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can accept one of the answers by clicking the checkmark next to it. (You can change it later if a better answer comes along.) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more. Also, feel free to edit the question if you can make it more relevant to others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
string[] savetexts = new string[]{ savetext , savetext2 };
```

Comment: I was so close ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could convert the entire string and save it in a char array.

```
char[] savetext = savetext.ToCharArray();
char[] savetext2 = savetext2.ToCharArray();
```

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

P.S It is much easier to use a List instead of hard-coded arrays like above.

```
List<String> myStrings = new List<String>();
myStrings.add(savetext);
myStrings.add(saveText2);
```

.....etc

then to get them back you iterate over myStrings

```
foreach(String s in myStrings){
  Console.writeline(s);
}
```

Or you can access them directly

```
String text1 = myStrings[0];
String text2 = myString[1];
```

This is a bit more than what you are asking, but using List becomes much easier in the long run. Best of luck.